# PHP Mail, combing all messages into one area

Tags: php

Im having trouble having all of the messages combine in one box. Currently its all separate messages for every sent and received. The html code is message_send.html and the php code is message_send.php. I am using a php script called etano - http://www.datemill.com/

```
HTML
    !--opt name="output.flirt_reply"-->
    <p><a class="content-link link_flirt" href="{tplvars.relative_url}flirt_send.php?to_id={output.fk_user_id}&amp;ft=1&amp;return={output.return}"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>Reply with a flirt instead</a></p>
<!--/opt name="output.flirt_reply"-->

<form action="{tplvars.relative_url}processors/message_send.php" method="post" id="msend_form">
<fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="fk_user_id" value="{output.fk_user_id}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="{output.return}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="refnum" value="{output.refnum}" />
    <label for="subject" id="subject">Subject: </label><input class="text" type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="{output.subject}" tabindex="1" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <textarea name="message_body" id="message_body" cols="" rows="" tabindex="2" class="sco_bbcode">{output.message_body}</textarea>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="controls">
    <p>
    <a class="content-link plain thickbox" href="{tplvars.relative_url}popup_use_tpl.php?mail_id={output.mail_id}&amp;return={output.return}&amp;keepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=500&amp;width=750" id="popup_use_tpl">Use a saved message</a>
    <input class="button large" id="btn_savetpl" type="submit" value="Save as Template" tabindex="4" />
    </p>

    <input class="button medium reply" type="submit" value="Send" tabindex="3" />
</fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{tplvars.relative_url}js/thickbox.js?v={tplvars.js_lib_v}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{tplvars.relative_url}js/message_send.js?v={tplvars.js_lib_v}"></script>
<!--opt name="output.bbcode_message"-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{tplvars.relative_url}js/bbcode.js?v={tplvars.js_lib_v}"></script>
<!--/opt name="output.bbcode_message"-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lang=new Array('{output.lang_263}','{output.lang_264}','{output.lang_196}','{output.lang_197}');
</script>

PHP

  <?php
/******************************************************************************
Etano
===============================================================================
File:                       message_send.php
$Revision: 679 $
Software by:                DateMill (http://www.datemill.com)
Copyright by:               DateMill (http://www.datemill.com)
Support at:                 http://www.datemill.com/forum
*******************************************************************************
* See the "docs/licenses/etano.txt" file for license.                         *
******************************************************************************/

require 'includes/common.inc.php';
require _BASEPATH_.'/includes/user_functions.inc.php';
require _BASEPATH_.'/includes/tables/user_inbox.inc.php';
require _BASEPATH_.'/skins_site/'.get_my_skin().'/lang/mailbox.inc.php';

$tpl=new phemplate(_BASEPATH_.'/skins_site/'.get_my_skin().'/','remove_nonjs');

$output=$user_inbox_default['defaults'];
if (isset($_SESSION['topass']['input'])) {
    $output=$_SESSION['topass']['input'];
    $output['_user_other']=get_user_by_userid($output['fk_user_id']);
    unset($_SESSION['topass']['input']);
    $temp='message_write';
    if (isset($_SESSION[_LICENSE_KEY_]['user'][$output['refnum']])) {
        $temp=$_SESSION[_LICENSE_KEY_]['user'][$output['refnum']];
    }
    check_login_member($temp);
} elseif (!empty($_GET['to_id'])) {
    $output['fk_user_id']=(int)$_GET['to_id'];
    $output['_user_other']=get_user_by_userid($output['fk_user_id']);
    check_login_member('message_write');
} elseif (!empty($_GET['mail_id'])) {
    $output['refnum']=mt_rand(10000,99999);
    $_SESSION[_LICENSE_KEY_]['user'][$output['refnum']]='message_reply';
    check_login_member('message_reply');
    $mail_id=(int)$_GET['mail_id'];
    $query="SELECT `mail_id`,`fk_user_id_other` as `fk_user_id`,`subject`,`message_body`,`_user_other`,`message_type` FROM `{$dbtable_prefix}user_inbox` WHERE `mail_id`=$mail_id AND `fk_user_id`='".$_SESSION[_LICENSE_KEY_]['user']['user_id']."'";
    if (!($res=@mysql_query($query))) {trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);}
    if (mysql_num_rows($res)) {
        $output=array_merge($output,mysql_fetch_assoc($res));
        $output['subject']=(substr($output['subject'],0,3)=='Re:') ? $output['subject'] : 'Re: '.$output['subject'];
        if ($output['message_type']==MESS_MESS) {
            $output['message_body']="\n\n[quote]".$output['message_body'].'[/quote]';
        } else {
            $output['message_body']='';
        }
    }
    if (isset($_GET['gettpl'])) {
        $tpl_id=(int)$_GET['gettpl'];
        $query="SELECT `subject`,`message_body` FROM `{$dbtable_prefix}user_mtpls` WHERE `mtpl_id`=$tpl_id AND `fk_user_id`='".$_SESSION[_LICENSE_KEY_]['user']['user_id']."'";
        if (!($res=@mysql_query($query))) {trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);}
        if (mysql_num_rows($res)) {
            $output=array_merge($output,mysql_fetch_assoc($res));
        }
    }
// no need to sanitize
//  $output=sanitize_and_format($output,TYPE_STRING,$__field2format[TEXT_DB2EDIT]);
    if ($output['message_type']==MESS_FLIRT) {
        $output['flirt_reply']=true;
    }
} else {
    trigger_error($GLOBALS['_lang'][120],E_USER_ERROR);
}
$output['lang_263']=sanitize_and_format($GLOBALS['_lang'][263],TYPE_STRING,$__field2format[TEXT_DB2DISPLAY]);
$output['lang_264']=sanitize_and_format($GLOBALS['_lang'][264],TYPE_STRING,$__field2format[TEXT_DB2DISPLAY]);
$output['lang_196']=sanitize_and_format($GLOBALS['_lang'][196],TYPE_STRING,$__field2format[TEXT_DB2DISPLAY]);
$output['lang_197']=sanitize_and_format($GLOBALS['_lang'][197],TYPE_STRING,$__field2format[TEXT_DB2DISPLAY]);

if (!isset($output['return']) && isset($_GET['return'])) {
    $output['return']=sanitize_and_format_gpc($_GET,'return',TYPE_STRING,$__field2format[FIELD_TEXTFIELD] | FORMAT_RUENCODE,'');
}

$output['bbcode_message']=get_site_option('bbcode_message','core');
if (empty($output['bbcode_message'])) {
    unset($output['bbcode_message']);
}
$tpl->set_file('content','message_send.html');
$tpl->set_var('output',$output);
$tpl->process('content','content',TPL_OPTIONAL);

$tplvars['page_title']=sprintf($GLOBALS['_lang'][137],$output['_user_other']);
$tplvars['title']=$tplvars['page_title'];
$tplvars['page']='message_send';
$tplvars['css']='message_send.css';
if (is_file('message_send_left.php')) {
    include 'message_send_left.php';
}
include 'frame.php';
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're tying to accomplish.

Comment: [Image link](http://s9.postimg.org/bmimmhyzj/inbox.png) - Check out the link, each message is separate, use Facebook and other social networking sites as an example, messages from user to user are combined in one message box, thats what im trying to accomplish

Comment: So you want to collect mail from many sources and display them all in the same Inbox view correct?

Comment: By collect mail you mean a message system where users message back and forth and its all in one box yes...Example, lets say you and me email, its in one thread, and then lets say i email Mr.XYZ. Its a separate thread but my messages with Mr.XYZ is in its own message box...Am i explaining that clear enough? - Basically just a typical inbox where things arent scattered all over the place

Comment: So a threaded view I think, similar to GMail. Instead of each message having it's own line. Is that more correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. I was thinking it was called nested view but google threaded and that seems to be what it is called.